# C++: How to put multiple lines on std::string data("here");

Tags: c++, batch-file, enter

I need to write a .batch file; how can I insert multiple lines?

See: std::string data("");

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int name;

std::cout << "Insert your name";
std::cin >> name;
const char *path="C:/Users/Public/Desktop/file.bat";
std::ofstream file(path);
std::string data( /* "FIRST LINE + ENTER + SECOND LINE + name + ENTER + THIRD LINE"*/ );
file << data;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to insert line breaks?

Comment: You must be kidding.

Comment: @LogicStuff I'm pretty new to all of this. Sorry about that

Comment: @Lorenzo Bad research - that's all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\n` for line breaks.

```
std::string data("FIRST LINE\nSECOND LINE\nTHIRD LINE");
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how can I insert the variable "name" in the batch file?

Comment: @Lorenzo: You should really read a C++ book or tutorial. That's *very* basic stuff. Stackoverflow is not the right place to start learning C++ from zero. Hint: C++, like some other programming languages, supports `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still get an error ([Error] invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [12]' to binary 'operator+'). Could you help me?

Comment: @Lorenzo: `+` only works if at least one of the operands is of type `std::string`. You cannot concatenate two string literals. An easy solution is to turn one of the string literals into an `std::string`, then concatenate. Example: `"foo" + std::string("bar")`

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can also use raw string literal:

```
    std::string data(
R"(line 1
line 2
line 3
...)"
    );
```